# How to add events and store them in a database for android calendar widget?

Tags: java, android, events, calendar, widget

This is my first app every to try to make, and it's been tough to try to teach myself from scratch. I've been learning how to use the android.widget.CalendarView libary in Android Studio to create a basic calendar, but I've been having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to add an event to a date and store it in a database. Here's all of the code for it. I have three classes so far:

1: Main

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button goToCalendarButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        goToCalendarButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goToCalendarButton);
        goToCalendarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalendarActivity.class);

                //intent.putExtra();

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2: Calendar

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CalendarView calendar;

    Button selectDateButton;
    Button goHomeButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

        selectDateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectDateButton);
        selectDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CalendarActivity.this, DateActivity.class);

                //intent.putExtra();

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        goHomeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goHomeButton);
        goHomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CalendarActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                //intent.putExtra();

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar1);
        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected date "+(month+1)+"/"+dayOfMonth+"/"+year,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

3: Date

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button goHomeButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_date);

        goHomeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goHomeButton);
        goHomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DateActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                //intent.putExtra();

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

4: Event

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button goHomeButton;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);

            goHomeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goHomeButton);
            goHomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(EventActivity.this,                            MainActivity.class);
                    //intent.putExtra();

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

It's been very difficult to learn and understand everything and this is due by the 17th as 50% of my grade, so any help is much appreciated!